# Drupal 7 - Hide certain form fields of a content edit form depending on the content data

Tags: forms, drupal, permissions, field

In Drupal 7, is there a way to change the standard edit form for a content type based on a certain content?

For example:

I have a content type with a checkbox...once it it checked and the form is saved, I do not want this checkbox to be visible anymore...therefore based on the checkboxes value in the Database I want to hide form fields when showing the form.

I am building a small specific project site, where a company wants to add projects, and their customers are supposed to follow certain steps (upload some content, provide information etc.), and also should be able to check off certain requirements, and once these are checked off, they should not be visible/editable to them.

Also the displayed form fields should depend on an user's role, and then FURTHER be limited depending on the content's database entries.

Is there a module, which could achieve this behaviour? "rules" and "field/permissions" come close to what I need, but are not sufficient. Or did I just miss the option to change a form field's accessibility based on conditions?

What I need is some place to define a logic like "IF (VALUEOF(CHECKBOX_1) == TRUE) THEN DO_NOT_SHOW(CHECKBOX_1)"

Comment: Why not using hook_form_alter? You can get all values there and disable/remove elements.

Comment: By default, Drupal does not offer such feature out of the box. Since your requirements are very specific, hook_form_alter is the only option you can use. You need to check the value in particular field and then make it hidden. Or try with dependent/conditional field module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    switch($form_id) {
    case 'nameOfTheNode_node_form':
        //your code here. check the value from from_state.
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use switch and not an if statement? Are there many forms to alter?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but yes, maybe in the same module you want to alter 2 forms.

Comment: This function is called for every form, when ever it's going to be displayed, so make sure to change the right one, by checking it's id.

Answer (score 13):

hook_form_alter is the way to do this, as explained by Mihaela, but what options do you have inside that function?

- If you want just to disable field (it will be visible, but user can't change it) you can do it like this:

  `$form['field_myfield']['#disabled'] = TRUE;`
- And if you want it to be hidden, but to keep value it has before editing the way to do that is:

  `$form['field_myfield']['#access'] = FALSE;`

I.e. hiding it (somewhere I saw someone suggesting that):

```
hide($form['field_myfield']);
```

really hides the field, but after that, when form is saved this field has empty value, validation fails, etc, so that's not a good way to do this. Hiding makes sense only if you want to print separately that field later, at some other place.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I use module **Conditional Fields** https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

For example: If my Dependees field has a value, Dependent field can be visible/invisible, enabled/disabled, required/optional, checked/unchecked