# How to programatically unhide Drupal 7 content field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On my company's Drupal 7 site, I created a field for one of our content types through the admin UI.  We decided to hide it from the user until some styling changes make it through to production.  Is there a was to programmatically unhide the field via an update hook?  I know get at least some of the field information through the field_info_field function, but I'm not sure how if it contains the setting needed to make the field visible to the user.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

I know I can unhide it through the UI once the changes hit production, but it would be nice to have an automated way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it programmatically from it's node template with `hide()` function:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7.x

You can do that conditionally, i.e. by checking user role first.

Now, I'm not sure will this work from update hook, and I'm not even sure why you want to use that hook?!? If users are allowed to edit that content type and you actually want to hide it from edit form then check out my answer here:

[Drupal 7 - Hide certain form fields of a content edit form depending on the content data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774263/drupal-7-hide-certain-form-fields-of-a-content-edit-form-depending-on-the-cont/21041471#21041471)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions drupal module to hide and unhide fields to users of specific role.Initially during development the field can be made visible to admin role and then later on the permission can be granted to users of other roles